# Append rows in HTML table with jquery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, jquery-append

I am using a `for` loop to append multiple rows in my HTML table using `jquery`.

The `for` loop *(code below)* runs on the response of an `ajax` call which returns an `array of arrays`. But only 1 row gets added to the table irrespective of no. of elements in the array.

The actual response object is quite large, so I am attaching a [Google Drive link for a reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gH6_MubLS-5bZ2akY2t0bTvRTQ_xi3nt/view?usp=sharing)

**How do I append all the rows in the table?**

*Code snippet (using Jquery)*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#ghsubmitbtn').on('click', function(e) {

                var data = JSON.stringify(JSONObj);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api-crt.cert.havail.sabre.com/v4.2.0/shop/flights?mode=live&limit=50&offset=1',
                    method: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: data,
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + bat
                    },

                    success: function(data) {
                        var BookBtn = '<input type="submit" value="Book" name="book" class="btn btn-primary">';

                        for (var v = 0; v <= 999; v++) {
                            for (var b = 0; b <= 999; b++) {
                                for (var m = 0; m <= 999; m++) {

                                    var row = $('<tr><td>' + data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].SequenceNumber + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].DepartureDateTime + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].ArrivalDateTime + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].DepartureAirport.LocationCode + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].ArrivalAirport.LocationCode + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].DepartureDateTime + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].ArrivalDateTime + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].DepartureAirport.LocationCode + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].ArrivalAirport.LocationCode + '</td><td>' +
                                        data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m].OperatingAirline.Code + '</td><td>' +
                                        BookBtn + '</td></tr>');

                                    $('#tblData').append(row);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

> JSON Exception in the console for an undefined JSON property

**Resolution**

> Safely Access Deeply Nested Values In JavaScript

[Read this](https://medium.com/javascript-inside/safely-accessing-deeply-nested-values-in-javascript-99bf72a0855a) article to avoid JSON exceptions in future.

**Correction**

```
if (data && data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS && data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries && data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v] && data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary && data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions && data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b] && data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment && data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[b].FlightSegment[m]) {
    // Build row using nested JSON
}
```

**[Corrected JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcujLm2v/15/)**

---

P.S To quickly debug, you must always check `browser console` to look for any JSON exceptions. Almost 90% of issues get resolved with the error strings displayed. To understand the real issue, I did the same :)

Comment: I edited like this. But , still , I get only 1 response to the table. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: I have updated my answer. This should definitely unblock you. Keep me in the loop :)

Comment: It Worked !! And also how can get `data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItineraryPricingInfo[0].ItinTotalFare.BaseFare.Amount` and 
`data.OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.PricedItineraries.PricedItinerary[v].AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption[0].FlightSegment[0].TPA_Extensions.Mileage.Amount`. I tried like this. But , I couldn't get the response.

Comment: hint - use a debugger to check values till previous keys of the nested JSON  (one after another)

Comment: I tried.. But , I couldn't do it.. Please if you can , give me some help..